# ArrayList to sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I'm new to android.I wanna to fill my SharedPreference from ArrayList..
how can I place details to preferences.. preference screen contain some edittext and radiobutton sections

```
ArrayList<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<Info>();
        InfoHandler infoHandler = new InfoHandler();
        infoList = infoHandler.load(getActivity(), profileId);// rename
        //System.out.println(infoList.size());
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        // editor.putString("prefProfileName",infoList.get(0));
```

How can I extract each element from Arraylist and place to preference screen

Comment: Have you tried this answer [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: Use database instead of SharedPreference for storing list of custom objects.

Comment: If you don't want to use a DB, maybe convert the list to json and save?

Comment: @YeLinAung I used SharedPreferences. sorry for too late reply . mean while I found the answer to use SharedPreferences.

Comment: @SoniyaMohan Great, as long as it works for you.